# Issue with Group by in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

My database design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rm2e.png

I am trying to use below code :

```
$myselect = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        reason.ReasonName,
        tblexam.EXAMDATE,
        tblexam.EXAMTIME,
        prefix.PREFIXABB,
        studentmaster.STUDENTNAME,
        studentmaster.STUDENTSURNAME,
        studentmaster.STUDENTCODE,
        program.PROGRAMNAME,
        course.COURSENAMEENG 
    FROM 
        reason, 
        formlate, 
        tblexam, 
        studentmaster,
        prefix, 
        program, 
        course 
    WHERE 
        reason.ReasonID = formlate.ReasonID AND
        formlate.CLASSID = tblexam.CLASSID AND
        formlate.COURSEID = formlate.COURSEID AND
        formlate.ROOMID = formlate.ROOMID AND
        prefix.PREFIXID = studentmaster.PREFIXID AND
        formlate.STUDENTID = studentmaster.STUDENTID AND
        program.PROGRAMID = studentmaster.PROGRAMID AND
        course.COURSEID = tblexam.COURSEID
    GROUP BY 
        reason.ReasonID,studentmaster.STUDENTID 
    ORDER BY 
        reason.ReasonID ASC");

<body>
    <?php $i =1;
        while($rowfet = mysql_fetch_array($myselect)){
         ?>
        <h2><?php echo $rowfet['ReasonName']; ?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo DateThai($rowfet['EXAMDATE']) . ' ' . MorningEvening($rowfet['EXAMTIME']); ?></h3>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>studentid </th>
            <th>Fullname </th>
            <th>Program  </th>
            <th>Coursename </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['STUDENTCODE']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['PREFIXABB'] . $rowfet['STUDENTNAME'] . ' '.$rowfet['STUDENTSURNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['PROGRAMNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['COURSENAMEENG']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
```

but it shows the result like :

---

```
Reason1
10 Jan 2015 (Morning)
| No   | studentid |  Fullname | Program  |  Coursename |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  111111   |   John    |   ProgA  |     Math    |
---------------------------------------------------------
Reason1
10 Jan 2015 (Morning)
| No   | studentid |  Fullname | Program  |  Coursename |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  2222222   |   Jane   |   ProgB  |     Math    |
-----------------------------------
Reason2
10 Jan 2015 (Evening)
| No   | studentid |  Fullname | Program  |  Coursename |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  3   |  3333333  |   Hawk    |   ProgB  |     Math    |
-----------------------------------
```

I want the result to show like :

```
Reason1
10 Jan 2015 (Morning)
| No   | studentid |  Fullname | Program  |  Coursename |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  111111   |   John    |   ProgA  |     Math    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  2222222   |   Jane   |   ProgB  |     Math    |
-----------------------------------
Reason2
10 Jan 2015 (Evening)
| No   | studentid |  Fullname | Program  |  Coursename |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  3333333  |   Hawk    |   ProgB  |     Math    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to group table by

- Reasonname
- Examdate
- Examtime

Please help, I'm a newbie.

I've create database in SQLFiddle Here this please try and help:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1)

Comment: Your query seems so haaard to read^^ Pls edit your post.

Comment: Question asked clear, very nice! I will try to answer it now.

Comment: Could you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: You may be a newbie, but this is a mess, and besides, you shouldn't use PHP's long since deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: @Julo0sS I've edited my post, please try to read again ^^

Comment: @marijnz0r thanks for kindly understand.

Comment: @Strawberry Please try to be kind to this guy, he is new and I could easily understand what he tried to accomplish.

Comment: @marijnz0r This is me trying ;-)

Comment: @ibearkp (thx for editing ;) ) Why do you group it by studentmaster.STUDENTID ? isn't it just enough to group it by reasonId? (isn't that just what you wish btw?)

Comment: @Julo0sS if I group it only by reasonid the record will not show if same student late by other reason and the one reason will show only one record. Do you have some code for me ? , Thanks for kindly understand.

Comment: Can anyone show me some code ? I didn't get that cause my problem is "How to get them record by loop?" Thanks.

Comment: @ibearkp 1st of all, you should build a sqlfiddle.com, this would make things much easier to help you :) Just get your "create" queries + data from your db manager and paste/run it there... this really helps...

Comment: @ibearkp After reading it again, I think that you make things more difficult than what they really are... The problem could be easily fixed with your php code... Displaying the results just need an ordered sequence, here you just do not make any difference on the reasons.. gimme a few minutes ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS I've create SQLFiddle please follow this link [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1

Comment: @ibearkp I wrote an answer that should solve your issue...

Comment: @ibearkp IMO, your problem did not come from your sql, but only from the fact that you "open a new table" for each row you fetch... ;)

Comment: @ibearkp The sqlFiddle you just made is not related at all to the picture you posted... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considered that you have a sql result that looks like this, ordered by reason, date and time :

```
reason.reasonName | examDate | examTime | prefix | studentName | studentSurname | studentCode | ProgramName | courseName
```

with a few records, like :

```
1 | someDate1 | someTime1 | A | James | Jim | 123 | PA | PACourse
1 | someDate1 | someTime1 | A | Tommy | Tim | 222 | PC | PCCourse
1 | someDate2 | someTime2 | B | James | Jim | 123 | PB | PBCourse

2 | someDate1 | someTime1 | C | Jamie | Jam | 444 | PD | PDCourse
2 | someDate1 | someTime1 | E | Willy | Wil | 555 | PE | PECourse
2 | someDate2 | someTime2 | F | Cathy | Cat | 777 | PF | PFCourse
2 | someDate2 | someTime2 | G | David | Dav | 844 | PL | PLCourse
2 | someDate3 | someTime3 | L | James | Jim | 123 | PM | PMCourse

3 | someDate4 | someTime4 | W | Ibear | Ibe | 999 | PX | PXCourse
```

Here, you get this kind of data, you have, 
for reason 1 :

- 2 students with exam at the same day/time (time1)
- 1 student with axam at another time (time2)

for reason 2 :

- 2 students with exam at the same day/time (time1)
- 2 students with exam at the same day/time (time2)
- 1 student with exam at another time (time3)

for reason 3 :

- 1 student with exam at time 4

SO, you want to display :

2 tables for reason 1 (time1 / time2)

3 tables for reason 2 (time1 / time2 / time3)

1 table for reason 3

CONSIDERED that the table, when you get it from your SQL is REALLY oredered like what I wrote above, you have to make your checks on fetch :

```
<?php
    //YOU WILL HAVE TO CHECK THESE VARS TO MAKE IT CLEAR, IF SAME TABLE OR NOT
    $i = false;
    //I use $i as a table detector, false at start, once a table has been opened it is turned as true

    $reason = "";
    //I will keep the latest reasonName in this

    $examDate = "";
    //I will keep the latest examDate in this

    $examTime = "";
    //I will keep the latest examTime in this

    $yourDisplay = "";
    //In yourDisplay, i keep the text i have to display (tables, data...)

    $closeTable = "</tbody></table>";
    //This is the code you need to close a table.

    while($rowfet = mysql_fetch_array($myselect)){
        if(($rowfet['ReasonName']!=$reason)||(DateThai($rowfet['EXAMDATE'])!=$examDate)||(MorningEvening($rowfet['EXAMTIME'])!=$examTime)){
            //YOU GET HERE IF YOU HAVE DIFFERENT REASON/DATE/TIME, SO YOU HAVE TO MAKE A NEW TABLE

            $reason = $rowfet['ReasonName'];
            $examDate = DateThai($rowfet['EXAMDATE']);
            $examTime = MorningEvening($rowfet['EXAMTIME']);

            //NOW CHECK IF YOU ALREADY HAVE WRITTEN A TABLE BEFORE
            if($i == true){
                //You already have written a table before
                $yourDisplay.=$closeTable;
            }else{
                //This is the first table you write
                $i=true;
            }
            $yourDisplay.=" <h2>".$reason."</h2>
                            <h3>".DateThai($examDate)." ".MorningEvening($examTime)."</h3>
                            <table width='100%' border='1'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>studentid</th>
                                    <th>fullname</th>
                                    <th>Program</th>
                                    <th>Coursename</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>".$rowfet['STUDENTCODE']."</td>
                                    <td>".$rowfet['PREFIXABB']." ".$rowfet['STUDENTNAME']." ".$rowfet['STUDENTSURNAME']."</td>
                                    <td>".$rowfet['PROGRAMNAME']."</td>
                                    <td>".$rowfet['COURSENAMEENG']."</td>
                                </tr>";

        }else{
            //YOU ARE ALREADY IN A TABLE! WITH SAME REASON/TIME/DATE
            //YOUR RECORD JUST NEEDS TO BE ADDED IN A NEW LINE
            $yourDisplay.="<tr>
                            <td>".$rowfet['STUDENTCODE']."</td>
                            <td>".$rowfet['PREFIXABB']." ".$rowfet['STUDENTNAME']." ".$rowfet['STUDENTSURNAME']."</td>
                            <td>".$rowfet['PROGRAMNAME']."</td>
                            <td>".$rowfet['COURSENAMEENG']."</td>
                           </tr>";
        }
    }
    //ONCE OUT, CLOSE THE LAST TABLE AND DISPLAY YOUR DATA
    if($i==1){
        $yourDisplay.=$closeTable;
    }

    echo $yourDisplay;
?>
```

In My Opinion, this kind of approach should solve your problem IF THE SQL QUERY returns the rows as explained above. (seems like it is the case)

EDIT :

You asked to "not display" the reasonname if it was the same, so just look at the line you see this :

```
$yourDisplay.=" <h2>".$reason."</h2>
                <h3>".DateThai($examDate)." ................ code continue
```

and replace it with this :

```
if($rowfet['ReasonName']!=$reason){
    $yourDisplay.="<h2>".$reason."</h2>";
}
$yourDisplay.="<h3>".DateThai($examDate)." ".MorningEvening($examTime)."</h3>
                        <table width='100%' border='1'>
        //.... continue the code
```

Comment: Thanks, This work !! ,but still show 'reasonname' again for 2 times

Comment: @ibearkp can you explain? I don't understand what you mean with "show reasonname again for 2 times"...

Comment: It's show like
**Reasonname1**
Examtime
.....record...
**Reasonname1**
Examtime2
....record..
I want it to show like : **Reasonname1**
Examtime
.....record...
Examtime2
....record..

Comment: this is ok. This is only because i fetch your tab considering that each tab has to have the same REASON + DATE + TIME to show the results. If not, just move something from the condition. If you want to have your tab only on reason name, then move out your if == with date and time... got it?

Comment: @ibearkp Np ;) Remember this is only a "PHP" solution to help you display your results correctly, Even if it works fine, you can still improve your sql ;) Bye! :)

Comment: my database server has broke, and it just work today, so I'm try your edited code but and 'Reasonname' is disappear from page. I think it's because $reason = $rowfet['ReasonName'] so it's always the same value. Did I wrong ? Please help. thank you again

Comment: Yes, it's always the same, so it's not get into loop if($rowfet['rn'] != $reason){...

Answer (score -1):

You're looping through all your rows and creating a table for each of the rows.
What you want to do is to create a new table only if a sequence of a new `ReasonName` starts.

```
$myselect = mysql_query("SELECT reason.ReasonName,tblexam.EXAMDATE,tblexam.EXAMTIME,prefix.PREFIXABB,studentmaster.STUDENTNAME,studentmaster.STUDENTSURNAME,studentmaster.STUDENTCODE,program.PROGRAMNAME,course.COURSENAMEENG FROM reason, formlate, tblexam, studentmaster,prefix, program, course WHERE reason.ReasonID = formlate.ReasonID AND formlate.CLASSID = tblexam.CLASSID AND formlate.COURSEID = formlate.COURSEID AND formlate.ROOMID = formlate.ROOMID AND prefix.PREFIXID = studentmaster.PREFIXID AND formlate.STUDENTID = studentmaster.STUDENTID AND program.PROGRAMID = studentmaster.PROGRAMID AND course.COURSEID = tblexam.COURSEID GROUP BY reason.ReasonID,studentmaster.STUDENTID ORDER BY reason.ReasonID ASC");

<body>
    <?php $i =1;
        while($rowfet = mysql_fetch_array($myselect)){
         ?>
        <h2><?php echo $rowfet['ReasonName']; ?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo DateThai($rowfet['EXAMDATE']) . ' ' . MorningEvening($rowfet['EXAMTIME']); ?></h3>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>studentid </th>
            <th>Fullname </th>
            <th>Program  </th>
            <th>Coursename </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo "You should create a loop here to loop through your ReasonNames"; ?>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['STUDENTCODE']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['PREFIXABB'] . $rowfet['STUDENTNAME'] . ' '.$rowfet['STUDENTSURNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['PROGRAMNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowfet['COURSENAMEENG']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php echo "Your loop should end here"; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: There's so much wrong with the original query, it's pointless trying to fix the PHP.

Comment: He has to start somewhere. This fixes part of his problem.